# I using create-react-app my-app --scripts-version=react-scripts-ts to create a react project with typescript, but it can't run

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript

this is error:

[image]

I run `yarn start` when the cli installed and don't change anything. Here is error place in @types directory:

[image]

I try to use  `create-react-app my-app --scripts-version=react-scripts-ts@2.8.1` to find something, but the result is same.

Comment: It looks like you have two copies of the React typings installed and they are conflicting.  One of them is at `E:/my-app/node_modules/@types/react/index.d.ts`.  Can you tell where the other copy is?  Try a "jump to definition" on `Element`.

Comment: Thank you very much! I find problem with your suggestion. In E: have a node_modules file. And when I delete it, the cli is running well.